# iPad app not laying out properly

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, ios-simulator

I have an iPad app that I've inherited the code for.

I'm relatively new to iPad development, so please bear with me...

The app was compiled off-site by a contractor in 2010. Since then, my company has been acquired and we're in the process of rebranding. My seemingly simple task is to replace our logo in this app with a new logo. It should take a few minutes - just drop a new logo into the code, compile, and bam! Done.

There's a problem with compiling the code...the working app launches in landscape mode and fills the entire screen with its interface. When I compile the app in the simulator or run it on my iPad (connected to my mac via USB cable), the screen launches in landscape mode, but the view is in portrait mode. In intermittent places throughout the app, the views switch from landscape to portrait layout.

This is driving me nuts because I don't even know what to look for. I see some references to shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation - I think that's been deprecated. Could that be causing the problem?

I know a LOT has changed since 2010. I'm currently running the latest version of XCode on a new mac. (From what I understand, my predecessor never actually compiled the app here, but relied totally on the contractor...from what I can see, this may be a problem that's been there all along, but nobody was aware of)

**UPDATE**

I have an older mac (with an older version of XCode) to test with. I've moved the app code onto the older mac, changed a few settings, and it works correctly.

I've also noticed the layout isn't quite correct on ANY app I create on my new mac. For example, dropping a button near the top of the form winds up scrolled off the top of the app, so it's not even visible.

Is there a setting in XCode that defines this behavior?

Comment: See `Controlling What Interface Orientations Are Supported (iOS 6)` section of [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html), also check the section `Understanding the Rotation Process (iOS 5 and earlier)` if you want to support older iOs versions.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6.0 check for view controller orientations condition is changed..

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: And also you have to set position controls for each control and change the frame accordingly dynamically that chance iOS has given to you..